# jQuery if visible

Tags: jquery

```
 <div id="chatCenterMembers">
   <div class="chatmember">
       <a title="Blah Blah Blah">
          <div class="newchatmessage" style="display: block;"></div>
```

How can I capture the visible div in an if statement?

I have `$(this)` set to `<div class="chatmember">` - second line from the top.

I've been working with below but had now luck so far.

```
if($(this+' a div.newchatmessage').filter(":visible")) {
```

Above just drops out...

I've also tried below and it doesn't work either

```
if ($(this + 'a div.newchatmessage').is(':visible')) {
```

Comment: Where is the div with the class `newchatmessage`?

Comment: @Wesley you may be right ... but `this` might not be a jQuery-variable, so i suppose `$('a div.newchatmessage', $(this))`

Comment: Oops deleted my comment too soon, I seem to remember using that syntax before but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

for any detailed information on this method, just scroll down a bit ... there's a bunch of examples!

edit (thanks for the hint @Wesley Murch):
if this does not work, your selector might be wrong ... `$(this+' a div.newchatmessage')` looks quite strange ... it might rather be `$('a div.newchatmessage', this)` or `$('a div.newchatmessage', $(this))` depending on `this` being a jQuery-variable or not

Comment: sorry - how would I use that in the if statement?

Comment: I think he means you should use `.is()` instead of `.filter()`.

Comment: Adding small example of your own is always helpful, see George answer.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard nope, sry ... i would only provide examples if the provided examples from the docu won't work as needed - if there's any additional need for explanation! (sorry, i'm a big friend of "google it" and giving at least some effort aka **reading** the docu) what should i look at? at a completely messed up answer? `$(this + 'a div.newchatmessage')`(sic!) can't be correct ...

Comment: Andrew - both of these worked $('a div.newchatmessage', this) or $('a div.newchatmessage', $(this)).... thx mate...

Comment: @Adam you are welcome, but you should mark the answer, which fitted your needs, as solution :)

Comment: @downvoter: would be nice if you give me a reason why you've downvoted my answer, so that i can elaborate!

Answer (score 49):

Use `.is()` to check if an element fills a certain requirement, like such:

```
if ($(this).find('a div.newchatmessage').is(':visible'))
```

Or, if you want it more readable:

```
var element = $(this).find('a div.newchatmessage');

if (element.is(':visible')) {
    // Do your thing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar situation and wanted to note that you should be wary of the jquery selector returning more than one element. I believe the .is(':visible') check will only evaluate the first element in the array. You can check to see if all elements returned by that selector are visible with something like this.

```
if($('.someElementWithThisClass:visible').length > 0){
    //Do it to it
}
```